# grep with regex for phone number

Tags: regex, grep

I would like to get the phone numbers from a file. I know the numbers have different forms, I can handle for a single one, but don't know how to get a uniform regex. For example

1. `xxx-xxx-xxxx`
2. `(xxx)xxx-xxxx`
3. `xxx xxx xxxx`
4. `xxxxxxxxxx`

I can only handle 1, 2, and 4 together

```
grep '[0-9]\{3\}[ -]\?[0-9]\{3\}[ -]\?[0-9]\{4\}' file
```

Is there any one single regex can handle all of these four forms?

Comment: You would have to handle 2 separately via alternation (|).  The issue is that using basic regex there's no way to tell whether the parens are balanced otherwise.

Comment: Check out Regexr for regex help... http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
grep '\(([0-9]\{3\})\|[0-9]\{3\}\)[ -]\?[0-9]\{3\}[ -]\?[0-9]\{4\}' file
```

Explanation:

`([0-9]\{3\})` three digits inside parentheses

`\|` or

`[0-9]\{3\}` three digits **not** inside parens

...with grouping parentheses - `\(...\)` - around the alternation so the rest of the regex behaves the same no matter which alternative matches.

Comment: The [slight] problem this RegEx is, it also matches a number with more than 4 digits in the last part, e.g. 123-123-12345 or a number with more than 10 digits in it. This: `grep '\(\(([0-9]\{3\})\|[0-9]\{3\}\)[ -]\?\)\{2\}[0-9]\{4\} '` should handle that nicely. See my reply below for explanation. Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers: Good point.  The OP only asked how to get the regex to match everything it should match, and I answered that.  Getting it to *not* match the things it shouldn't is much more interesting.

Comment: Note that another trick used here is the sequence "[ -]\?" This allows for matching a space, a hyphen, or any other character used to separate the groups of digits in the phone number.

Answer (score 9):

There are usually four patterns of phone numbers

```
1. xxx-xxx-xxxx         grep -o '[0-9]\{3\}\-[0-9]\{3\}\-[0-9]\{4\}'  file.txt
2. (xxx)xxx-xxxx        grep -o '([0-9]\{3\})[0-9]\{3\}\-[0-9]\{4\}'  file.txt
3. xxx xxx xxxx         grep -o '[0-9]\{3\}\s[0-9]\{3\}\s[0-9]\{4\}'  file.txt
4. xxxxxxxxxx           grep -o '[0-9]\{10\}' file.txt
```

In all

```
grep -o '\([0-9]\{3\}\-[0-9]\{3\}\-[0-9]\{4\}\)\|\(([0-9]\{3\})[0-9]\{3\}\-[0-9]\{4\}\)\|\([0-9]\{10\}\)\|\([0-9]\{3\}\s[0-9]\{3\}\s[0-9]\{4\}\)' file.txt
```

Of course, one could simplify the regex above but we can also leave this simplification to grep itself ~

Answer (score 7):

This is just a modified version of Alan Moore's solution. This is protected against some race condition where the last part of the number has more than four digits in it or the if the total number of digits are more than 10:

```
grep '\(\(([0-9]\{3\})\|[0-9]\{3\}\)[ -]\?\)\{2\}[0-9]\{4\} '
```

**Explanation:**

1. `\(([0-9]\{3\})\|[0-9]\{3\}\)` matches exactly three digits (e.g. 234)
   with or without surrounded by parentheses. `\|` performs the 'OR' operation.
2. The first `\( ... \)` groups together the above format followed by a `space` or `-` or `no space` at all - (`[ -]\?`) does that.
3. The `\{2\}` matches exactly two occurrences of the above
4. The `[0-9]\{4\} '` matches exactly one occurrence for a 4 digit number followed by a `space`

And it's a bit shorter as well. Tested on RHEL and Ubuntu. Cheers!!

Comment: awesome explanation! Saves me time to go look for a tutorial!

Answer (score 2):

You can just OR (`|`) your regexes together -- will be more readable that way too!

Comment: can you show me an example? I know OR(|) might work, but I didn't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that you may find it easier to see if your candidate number matches against *one of four* regular expressions. That will be easier to develop/debug, especially as/when you have to handle additional formats in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -P '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{3}\ [0-9]{3}\ [0-9]{3}|[0-9]{9}|\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

We can put all the required phone number validations one by one using an or condition which is more likely to work well (but tiresome coding).

```
grep '^[0-9]\{10\}$\|^[0-9]\{3\}[-][0-9]\{3\}[-][0-9]\{4\}$\|^[0-9]\{3\}[ ][0-9]\{3\}[ ][0-9]\{4\}$\|^[(][0-9]\{3\}[)][0-9]\{3\}[-][0-9]\{4\}$' phone_number.txt
```

returns all the specific formats :

- 920-702-9999
- (920)702-9999
- 920 702 9999
- 9207029999

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

`^(\d{10}|((([0-9]{3})\s){2})[0-9]{4}|((([0-9]{3})\-){2})[0-9]{4}|([(][0-9]{3}[)])[0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{4})$`

This is only applicable for the formate you mention above like:

1. `xxxxxxxxxx`
2. `xxx xxx xxxx`
3. `xxx-xxx-xxxx`
4. `(xxx)xxx-xxxx`

Answer (score 0):

+?(1[ -])?((\d{3})[ -]|(\d{3}[ -]?)){2}\d{4}

works for:

123-678-1234

123 678 1234

(123)-678-1234

+1-(123)-678-1234

1-(123)-678-1234

1 123 678 1234

1 (123) 678 1234

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oE '\(?\<[0-9]{3}[-) ]?[0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{4}\>'
```

Matches all your formats.

The `\<` and `\>` word boundaries prevent matching numbers that are too long, such as `123-123-12345` or `1234-123-1234`

Answer (score -2):

I got this:

```
debian:tmp$ cat p.txt
333-444-5555
(333)333-6666
123 456 7890
1234567890
debian:tmp$ egrep '\(?[0-9]{3}[ )-]?[0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{4}' p.txt
333-444-5555
(333)333-6666
123 456 7890
1234567890
debian:tmp$ egrep --version
GNU grep 2.5.3

Copyright (C) 1988, 1992-2002, 2004, 2005  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

debian:tmp$
```

Comment: This will match (333-444-555 also.