# Example of a regular expression for phone numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm very new to javascript, I just want a reqular expression for validating phone numbers for one of my text field.

I can accept `-+ () 0-9` from users, do you have regex for this one or a regex for phone numbers better then the one i need?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2842345/764846) rexeg

```
/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/
```

- (123) 456 7899
- (123).456.7899
- (123)-456-7899
- 123-456-7899
- 123 456 7899
- 1234567899

supported

Comment: what about my number 0208 123 1234 ? Please just check for numbers

Comment: @Mark: /\(?([0-9]{4})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/

Comment: Yes that is the regex but my comment is that there are so many possible splits of numbers and people don't always use the official ones - it is better just to accept numbers and forget the pattern

Comment: @Mark: aah. Yes... It's better

Comment: This seems to be US only, no support for international numbers

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
function validatePhone(phoneNumber){
   var phoneNumberPattern = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;  
   return phoneNumberPattern.test(phoneNumber); 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For Italian Phone number:

```
/^([+]39)?((3[\d]{2})([ ,\-,\/]){0,1}([\d, ]{6,9}))|(((0[\d]{1,4}))([ ,\-,\/]){0,1}([\d, ]{5,10}))$/
```

- +39 347 12 34 567
- 347-1234567
- 347/1234567
- 347 123456
- 3471234567
- 02/1234567
- 051 12 34 567

supported

Answer (score 3):

For global users have a look into this library [libphonenumber-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js).

this will let you validate global mobile numbers.

Answer (score 2):

For U.S. phone numbers:

```
/(((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-)|(\d{3}\.))?\d{3}(-|\.)\d{4})/g;
```

For U.S. hrefs with phone numbers:

```
/((\"tel:((\d{11})|(\d{10})|(((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-)|(\d{3}\.))?\d{3}(-|\.)\d{4}))\"))/g;
```

I know these are a bit clunky but they will catch most of the improperly formatted phone numbers you see around the internet.

Wanna see how it works in jquery?
Check out: https://jsfiddle.net/uohx1fo3/15/

Answer (score 0):

This regex works pretty widely for phone numbers:

```
^(\+)?(\d{1,2})?[( .-]*(\d{3})[) .-]*(\d{3,4})[ .-]?(\d{4})$
```