# Validate phone number in woocommerce checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add custom validation to the phone number in checkout page of woocommerce. How do I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BY default woocommerce already have regular expression validation. The easiest way would be to validate it through jquery.

EDIT: Try not to make any changes to the woocommerce core as they will be over ridden on next update. Try this code

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['shipping']['shipping_phone'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Phone', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('Phone', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );

     return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Where do i do the validation?

Comment: This code is to be used if the default validation is not working. Like in your case. If you need custom validation you should try using jquery which is the easiest option.

Comment: Ok i got it..after using your code I am able to access the field via javascript.Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

In my opinion there's no need to override default Woocommerce fields, nor use Javascript validation.
You can add a custom validation, that will be added to the Woocommerce's default billing phone field validation, hooking to an action triggered after submitting checkout.

This is the code I just implemented for a client.

```
// Custom validation for Billing Phone checkout field
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_validate_billing_phone');
function custom_validate_billing_phone() {
    $is_correct = preg_match('/^[0-9]{6,20}$/', $_POST['billing_phone']);
    if ( $_POST['billing_phone'] && !$is_correct) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'The Phone field should be <strong>between 6 and 20 digits</strong>.' ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Of course, instead of my `preg_match` you can check anything else and adjust your conditional code to your needs.

You can also add custom validation for other default fields, by checking on the right `$_POST` variable, or your own custom checkout fields, after you correctly set them up, of course, but this is another topic :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked really well, and with regex ^((\+\d{1,2}|1)[\s.-]?)?\(?[2-9](?!11)\d{2}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$ from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699007/regular-expression-to-match-standard-10-digit-phone-number#answer-38647720 gets you a really well validated, US phone number that can't start with 0 or 1, or have x11 as the area code.