# Woocommerce Checkout Indian Mobile Number Validation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have added this piece of code for validation of mobile number in woocommerce checkout field and regex is also working fine but here is little problem
1) When customer enters wrong mobile number wp_add_notice didn't print error message to customer
2) When customer enters right mobile number then error message has shown and customer goes to further payment options
**Summary : It doesn't print error message for wrong mobile number which i want.**

```
// Custom validation for Billing Phone checkout field
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_validate_billing_phone');
function custom_validate_billing_phone() {
    $is_correct = preg_match('/^[6-9]\d{9}$/', $_POST['billing_phone']);
    if ( $_POST['billing_phone'] && !$is_correct) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'The Mobile No. should be <strong>10 digits with starting 6,7,8,9</strong>.Try Again.' ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your condition is wrong. By using `$_POST['billing_phone']` you are retrieving the value of the array and not the presence of a value. `preg_match` is returning a number according to the documentation so your condition look something like : `if ( 6999999999 && !1)` which is wrong.

Comment: then please tell me what is the condition should i write

Comment: `if (preg_match('/^[6-9]\d{9}$/', $_POST['billing_phone']) === 0)`

Comment: its still having the same problem , when i enter wrong mobile number its shows nothing in error message but user still on the same page but if i put right mobile number then error message shows and user redirect to payment gateway

Comment: I have tested with `6999999999` which is matching and `4999999999` which is not and it's working. I am not talking about your redirection though. Can you give me the values you are testing ? Here is the code.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d4e224082f7f44549cebcd1a470cda75c516a40e

Comment: yeah you are right i also checked out the link which you have sent but error message is not showing in woocommerce after i put that code , if ( preg_match('/^[6-9]\d{9}$/', $_POST['billing_phone']) === 0)

Comment: wc_add_notice(sprintf( 'The Mobile No. should be <strong>10 digits with starting 6,7,8,9</strong>.Try Again.' ), 'error' ); , even not showing after adding "sprintf"

Comment: Try adding a simple print just before the `wc_add_notice` just to see if it's okay. I do not know `woocommerce` but it might be because it is a different version of PHP...

Comment: we can't use print before wc_add_notice

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there's no need to override default Woocommerce fields, nor use Javascript validation.
You can add a custom validation, that will be added to the Woocommerce's default billing phone field validation, hooking to an action triggered after submitting checkout.

This is the code I just implemented for a client.

```
// Custom validation for Billing Phone checkout field
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_validate_billing_phone');
function custom_validate_billing_phone() {
    $is_correct = preg_match('/^[0-9]{6,20}$/', $_POST['billing_phone']);
    if ( $_POST['billing_phone'] && !$is_correct) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'The Phone field should be <strong>between 6 and 20 digits</strong>.' ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Of course, instead of my preg_match you can check anything else and adjust your conditional code to your needs.

You can also add custom validation for other default fields, by checking on the right $_POST variable, or your own custom checkout fields, after you correctly set them up, of course, but this is another topic :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: you just pasted the sgaddo answer there is wrong thing to do mr. sukhjinder

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608371/validate-phone-number-in-woocommerce-checkout-page