# Custom phone validation in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to add custom validation to the phone number (billing_phone) on:

- Checkout page
- Register page
- My account page

---

- With 05
- Accept 10 numbers

I'm using [Validate phone number in woocommerce checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47873570/11987538) answer code, but it only works for the checkout page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Check I hope it works

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_process_registration_errors','custom_validate_billing_phone',10, 4 );
add_action('woocommerce_after_save_address_validation','custom_validate_billing_phone',1,2);
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_validate_billing_phone');

function custom_validate_billing_phone() {
    $is_correct = preg_match('/^05[0-9]{8}$/', $_POST['billing_phone']);
    
    if ( $_POST['billing_phone'] && !$is_correct ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'The Phone field should be <strong>start 05 and 10 digits</strong>.' ), 'error' );
    }
}
```