# What's wrong with this validation function?

Tags: javascript

I can’t validate phone number with this regular expression /^(?(\d{3}))?[..-/]?(\d{3})[.-/ ]?(\d{4})$/; The first three digits goes in the parenthesis (xxx) xxx-xxxx. I try to test the phone number with if/else loop but something is not working and I can't find what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for your help.

```
function validatePhone() {
    var pNumber = document.getElementById("phoneprompt").value;
    var regex = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[\.\.-\/]?(\d{3})[\.\-\/ ]?(\d{4})$/;

    if (regex.test(pNumber)) {
        document.getElementById("phoneprompt").innerHTML = "<img src=\"greencheck.png\" />";
        return (true);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("phoneprompt").innerHTML = "<img src=\"redcheck.png\" />&nbsp;Phone numbers must be in (xxx) xxx-xxxx format"; 
        return (false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share us how it is used.... also is there any error in the browser console

Comment: You are missing a space after area code. See https://regex101.com/r/vH1bH0/1

Answer (score 1):

Other than the problem with the regex, you can't set innerHTML of an input filed, so

```js
function validatePhone() {
  var el = document.getElementById("phoneprompt"),
    pNumber = el.value,
    regex = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?\s?[\.\.-\/]?(\d{3})[\.\-\/ ]?(\d{4})$/,
    valid = regex.test(pNumber);

  if (valid) {
    document.getElementById("phonepromptmsg").innerHTML = "<img src=\"greencheck.png\" />";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("phonepromptmsg").innerHTML = "<img src=\"redcheck.png\" />&nbsp;Phone numbers must be in (xxx) xxx-xxxx format";
  }

  return valid;
}
```

```html
<input id="phoneprompt" onchange="validatePhone()" />
<span id="phonepromptmsg"></span>
<br />
<input type="button" onclick="validatePhone()" value="Test"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[\.\.-\/]?(\d{3})[\.\-\/ ]?(\d{4})$/
```

to

```
/^\(?(\d{3})\)?\s?[\.\.-\/]?(\d{3})[\.\-\/ ]?(\d{4})$/
```

to accommodate a space optionally being after the area code, so both `(xxx) xxx-xxxx` and `(xxx)xxx-xxxx` will be matched.

---

However, here is a more robust 10-digit phone number regex where brackets and dashes are optional:

```
/^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$/
```

These will all be matched:

> (123)456-7890
>   (123) 456-7890
>   123-456-7890
>   123 456 7890

Ref: [Regular expression to match standard 10 digit phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699007/regular-expression-to-match-standard-10-digit-phone-number)