# Regex phonenumber

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone help me with a regex expression for a phone number

it needs to be in this format only

xxx-xxx-xxxx

Comment: What are you struggling with ?

Comment: Number of which country?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
^\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}$
```

Comment: ok how do i validate it in javascript so that it will only accept those regex values?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways are there. For example:

```
var regex = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/;
console.log(regex.test('999-999-9999'));
console.log(regex.test('9999-999-99999'));

//OR
var regex2 = /^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/
console.log(regex2.test('999-999-9999'));
console.log(regex2.test('9999-999-99999'));
```

You can also write specific to a country or area. See this ***[example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16699507/3894168)***.

If you are taking it from user `input` validate it like this:

```
var val = document.getElementbyId('yourInputId').value;
if(regex2.test(val)){
  alert("Success!!");
}
else{
  alert("Failure!!");
}
```