# How to write a regex only allow numbers and "(", ")", "-"

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is my regex but it seems not working

```
/[0-9\-\(\)]/.test(str)
```

when I test

```
 /[0-9\-\(\)]/.test('(12321)213213d')
```

It will return true

Comment: Are you trying to match a phone number? (seems so, given that character set) You may want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699007/regular-expression-to-match-standard-10-digit-phone-number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're actually testing is if *any* of those characters are in your test string. You want to check if it contains *only* those characters. To do that, you need to say from start `^` to finish `$` it only contains those chars.

e.g.

```
/^[0-9()-]+$/.test('(12321)213213d')
```

Answer (score 5):

Your current regex just checks that any one character in the string matches the character class. Add anchors and a quantifier: `/^[0-9\-\(\)]+$/`

- `^` - "Beginning of input" anchor
- `$` - "End of input" anchor
- `+` - Require one or more of the preceding thing

Mind you, `"()"` will match that regex. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You need to repeat it with either `*` or `+`. You also need to anchor it with `^` and `$` to contain the whole string.

```js
console.log(/^[0-9\-\(\)]+$/.test('(12321)213213d'));
console.log(/^[0-9\-\(\)]+$/.test('(12321)213213'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe adding input beginning/end characters will fix this. Like

```
^[0-9\-(\)]$/.exec('(12321)213213d')
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[\d\(\)\-]+$/.test('(12321)213213d')
```

^ start, $ end, \d for digit and ()-,

I think you are looking for telephone number matcher, if your answer is yes then this is not right regex for it.

for telephone matcher visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699007/regular-expression-to-match-standard-10-digit-phone-number)