# How to parse email or phone number parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The parameter **email_or_phone_number** comes from a client side and I need this for an authentication. However, the model has **email** and **phone number** fields separately.

What is the right way to parse the **email_or_phone_number** attribute, so then I could use find_by to find a user?

```
find_by(email: email, phone_number: phone_number)
```

If it's number, then it should become **phone_number**, but if it's not, then that is supposed to be an **email**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple readable solution for your question would be using an **OR** query

**Mongoid**

```
User.where(email: params[:email_or_phone_number])
    .or(phone_number: params[:email_or_phone_number])
    .first
```

***UPDATE* Active Record**

```
User.where(email: params[:email_or_phone_number])
    .or(User.where(phone_number: params[:email_or_phone_number]))
```

The other method could be using a Regex for identifying [Email Format](http://emailregex.com/) or [Phone Number Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699007/regular-expression-to-match-standard-10-digit-phone-number) of the value in `params[:email_or_phone_number]` but I have not come across any which are full proof in case of identifying there formats.

Comment: ArgumentError (You have passed Hash object to #or. Pass an ActiveRecord::Relation object instead.):

Comment: The above syntax is as per ODM i.e Mongoid

Comment: you could try || User.where(email: params[:email_or_phone_number])
    .or(User.where(phone_number: params[:email_or_phone_number]))

Comment: That has worked and it is neat solution! Please, update the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can split email or number with a regex.

```
 x = {email_or_phone_number:"3333"}
 x[:email_or_phone_number].match(/^\d+/)
```

if x is nil, then

```
 x[:email_or_phone_number].match(/\A([\w+\-]\.?)+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i)
```

else: is not valid input! Save result and pass res to `find_by`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the desired behavior is that searching for `123` matches both `greg123@example.com` (an email) and `123123123` (a phone number) then the correct query would be:

```
User.where('email ILIKE :q OR phone ILIKE :q',
           q: "%#{params[:email_or_phone]}%")
```

I'm not sure what your database is but keep in mind that this query may perform poorly on larger datasets. If that's the case I recommend you take a look at `pg_trgm` (Postgres-only) or full-text search solutions.