# Regex match cellphone number from string

Tags: regex, go

I want to match the right phone number from a string. For example:

```
string := "my phone number is 15817452367"
re := regexp.MustCompile(`1[34578][0-9]{9}`)
re.FindAllString(string, -1)
-> 15817452367
```

This result is right, but for another string:

```
string := "my card number is 115817452367"
re := regexp.MustCompile(`1[34578][0-9]{9}`)
re.FindAllString(string, -1)
-> 15817452367 (invalid)
```

This regex also matches the phone number, but I want this to not be a valid value，I don't want to get a phone number form a digital string. How can I fix the regex? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question. Maybe you want to use `^1[34578][0-9]{9}$` to indicate the begging and end of the string?

Or `(?:^|[^0-9])1[34578][0-9]{9}(?:$|[^0-9])`

Comment: What comes before he number? You need to qualify the start of the string somehow, which may just mean `^`. It's always "safest" to anchor your regexes at one or both ends if you're trying to get an exact match.

Comment: @Acidic the second is what I want

Comment: Ah hopefully that regex works well. I set the begging to check for `start of text OR a non-digit character` that **does not** capture. Same with the end of the string. So you should be left with just the phone number!

Comment: Not sure how this isn't a duplicate for something like [Regular expression to match standard 10 digit phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699007/regular-expression-to-match-standard-10-digit-phone-number). If you have a number format, but sometimes that number format can be broken, then why use that number format? You can try maybe prepending `1?` to the regular expression otherwise just use something like `\b\d{9,}\b` ensuring the minimum/maximum requirements are met for your phone number formatting

Comment: @pangpang Wait a second, are you trying to match the first string but not the second? If so just add `\b` before and after your regex and you'll be fine. `\b1[34578]\d{9}\b`

Comment: @ctwheels Thanks a lot, It is a good solution!

Comment: You're very welcome! `\b` is a word boundary. It is used to match (without consuming any characters) between a `\w` and a non `\w` (between `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`). For more information about regular expression tokens, check out [regex101](https://regex101.com). They have fantastic documentation, regex explanation and testing available online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the beginning and end of the regex for the beginning/end of the string *or* a non-digit character and only capture the phone number.

**Here is some working Regex as an example:**

```
(?:^|[^0-9])(1[34578][0-9]{9})(?:$|[^0-9])
```

---

**In Golang**

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?:^|[^0-9])(1[34578][0-9]{9})(?:$|[^0-9])`)
submatch := re.FindStringSubmatch("Phone Number: 15817452367;")
if len(submatch) < 2 {
    // No match found
}
match := submatch[1]
```

---

**Explanation:**

Find the start of the string or a non-digit character.
Enclosed in non-capture group.

```
(?:^|[^0-9])
```

Find the phone number you are searching for.
Enclosed in capture group.

```
(1[34578][0-9]{9})
```

Find the end of the string or a non-digit character.
Enclosed in non-capture group.

```
(?:$|[^0-9])
```

Comment: It is nice answer! but for string ""my phone number is15817452367"", I hope   to get the phone number.

Comment: Yep, that works. That's just the result of the `match` variable.
https://play.golang.org/p/8U7IwHoEL0

Comment: @pangpang My absolute pleasure. Only took 2 seconds of my time!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the matched string is not preceded nor followed by digits.
In order to check this, nest your pattern between two `[^0-9]*`: it means "nothing or not a digit".

```
regexp.MustCompile(`[^0-9]*1[34578][0-9]{9}[^0-9]*`)
```

This way, `15817452367` will be detected as a match, but `115817452367` will not.