# Python phone number regex

Tags: python, regex

I need your help:
I need to find all phone numbers in a passage of text, so I need to match different number formats, e.g: +420 123 123 123, 123 123 123, +420123123123 and/or 123123123.

If I use a regex pattern with the search method it works perfectly, but if I use findall method it just returns a list of whitespaces.

```
import re

def detect_numbers(text):
    phone_regex = re.compile(r"(\+420)?(\s*)?\d{3}(\s*)?\d{3}(\s*)?\d{3}")
    print(phone_regex.findall(text))
```

Comment: do the longer numbers always start with 420?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall Findall returns lists of tuples, with each tuple representing the groups from one match. You are grouping the whitespaces but you're not grouping the actual digits.

Comment: Change your groups into non-capturing groups. (?:\+420)? (?:\s*)? etc. Or capture the digits not white spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

Findall returns lists of tuples, with each tuple representing the groups from one match. You are grouping the whitespaces but you're not grouping the actual digits.

Try a regex that groups the digits too:

```
r"(\+420)?(\s*)?(\d{3})(\s*)?\(d{3})(\s*)?\(d{3})"
```

E.g.

```
def detect_numbers(text):
    phone_regex = re.compile(r"(\+420)?\s*?(\d{3})\s*?(\d{3})\s*?(\d{3})")
    print(phone_regex.findall(text))

detect_numbers("so I need to match +420 123 123 123, also 123 123 123, also +420123123123 and also 123123123. Can y")
```

prints:

```
[('+420', '123', '123', '123'), ('', '123', '123', '123'), ('+420', '123', '123', '123'), ('', '123', '123', '123')]
```

You could then string-join the group matches to get the numbers, e.g.

```
def detect_numbers(text):
    phone_regex = re.compile(r"(\+420)?\s*?(\d{3})\s*?(\d{3})\s*?(\d{3})")
    groups = phone_regex.findall(text)
    for g in groups:
        print("".join(g))

detect_numbers("so I need to match +420 123 123 123, also 123 123 123, also +420123123123 and also 123123123. Can y")
```

prints:

```
+420123123123
123123123
+420123123123
123123123
```

Comment: There's a difference between matching, and grouping. `r"This (is a) test"``Will *match* "This is a test", and there will be one subgroup containing "is a".

Answer (score 2):

Try regex like below for mobile number contains numbers

```
"/[^0-9 +\-]/"
```

If you want to starts with some particular number user like below

```
preg_match('\+420\d{9}/', mobilenumber)
```

Comment: @somesh remove the ^ in the set

Comment: @Oliver yeah ^ this one no need

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your text is relatively well behaved. Then a simple pattern could be to recover all sequence of at least nine digits, spaces and `-` optionally preceeded by a `+` with `re.findall`.

Unless your text contains some weird artifacts or arithmetic operations, this should do the trick. Furthermore, being loose on the format will allow to find numbers that contain format errors.

```
import re

def find_phone_numbers(text):
    phones = re.findall('(?:\+ *)?\d[\d\- ]{7,}\d', text)
    return [phone.replace('-', '').replace(' ', '') for phone in phones]
```

Example:

```
text = "My phone numbers are 123123123, +234-123-3231 and + 555 123 1234"

print(find_phone_numbers(text)) # ['123123123', '+2341233231', '+5551231234']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `findall` only returns non-overlapping matches, whereas search returns you the first match.

[findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result.

You can either use `search` or you can change your regular expression to

```
^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$
```

taken from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16699507/3664123).