# Regex to find phone number with country code from string

Tags: php, regex

I currently have the following:

```
    preg_match_all('/\b[0-9]{3}\s*-\s*[0-9]{3}\s*-\s*[0-9]{4}\b/',$cacax,$matches);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($matches[0]);
```

This will output:

```
[0] => 888-618-0367
```

instead of

```
 [0] => +1 888-618-0367
```

I got no clue on how to make that regex expression only match +1 starting numbers and also include the number in the match.

Will appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this page can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699007/regular-expression-to-match-standard-10-digit-phone-number

Comment: `/^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$/`

Comment: the expression from @Thefourthbird returns nothing as tested on https://www.phpliveregex.com/ when putting a number in a string context

Comment: the expression from @B001ᛦ also returns nothing when having a context like: xx  +1 442-444-2222  sxxxxTEST

Answer (score 0):

Add `\+1\s*` at the start, use

```
\+1\s*[0-9]{3}\s*-\s*[0-9]{3}\s*-\s*[0-9]{4}\b
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Yvrjw9/1). The `\+1\s*` part will require `+1` and zero or more whitespace characters at the start of your matches.

Comment: What if I want to get both numbers with/without any country code and not necessary +1 but any country code? just curious

Comment: @johnnasx Replace `1` with `\d+`