# Mask a phone number string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with a number:

```
const phoneNo = '2321392321';
```

and I want it to have this formt: (999) 999 - 9999.

Is it possible to do it with regex? I could split the number, take a substring, etc, but I feel like it'd be easier with regex, though I don't know how to tackle it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699007/regular-expression-to-match-standard-10-digit-phone-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```js
const phoneNo = '2321392321';

const formatted = phoneNo.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1) $2 - $3')

console.log(formatted)
```

In the regex, we are [capturing the digits into 3 separate groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges) and then we are back-referencing them inside `.replace` using `$1`, `$2` and `$3`