# Return the index of each string that contain a Phone Number? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to return the index of each string that contain a Phone Number.

```
var array = [
  'Just a Call Away, call 314-867-5309 ',
  'The Current city population is 3,443,940,573.',
  'My number is (123) 456-7890',
];

Expected Output: [0,2]
```

This is what I got so far, I used phoneRe as my regex. I can't seem to figure out how to filter out the string with 3,443,940,573 in my solution below.

```
function phoneNumber(p){
  var numArray = [];
  var phoneRe = /^[1-9]\d{2}[1-9]\d{2}\d{4}$/;
      
  for (var i = 0; i <p.length; i++){
    
    if (phoneRe.test(p[i].replace(/\D/g, ""))===true){
      numArray.push(i);
    }
}
  return numArray;
}

console.log(phoneNumber(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues. Your Regex is not as comprehensive as it could be. There are many phone number matching regexes available online. There are more than a few options in the StackOverflow Thread: [Regular expression to match standard 10 digit phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16699007/15497888)

The second issue is that you strip all non-numeric characters from your string `phoneRe.test(p[i].replace(/\D/g, ""))` which is an issue when the formatting of numbers is important to determining if your candidate is a phone number or not.

Use [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) instead to see if the pattern is present in your string.

```js
var array = [
    'Just a Call Away, call 314-867-5309 ',
    'The Current city population is 3,443,940,573.',
    'My number is (123) 456-7890',
];

function phoneNumber(p) {
    var numArray = [];
    var phoneRe = /(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}/g;

    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        if (p[i].search(phoneRe) !== -1) {
            numArray.push(i);
        }
    }
    return numArray;
}

console.log(phoneNumber(array));
```

If you wanted some more modern JavaScript Syntax

```js
const phoneRe = /(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}/g;
const phoneNumber = (numberStrings) => {
    return numberStrings.reduce((accumulator, current, index) => {
        if (current.search(phoneRe) !== -1) {
            accumulator.push(index);
        }
        return accumulator;
    }, []);
};

let strings = [
    'Just a Call Away, call 314-867-5309 ',
    'The Current city population is 3,443,940,573.',
    'My number is (123) 456-7890',
];

console.log(phoneNumber(strings));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var phoneRe = /(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?/img;
```

This regex should work better.