# R: Regex for Phone Numbers

Tags: r, regex

I am working with the R programming language.

I have a column of data that looks something like this:

```
string = c("a1 123-456-7899 hh", "b 124-123-9999 b3")
```

I would like to remove the "phone numbers" so that the final result looks like this:

```
[1] "a1 hh" "b  b3"
```

I tried to apply the answer provided here [Regular expression to match standard 10 digit phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699007/regular-expression-to-match-standard-10-digit-phone-number) to my question:

```
gsub("^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$", "", string, fixed = TRUE)
```

But I get the following error: `Error: '\+' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""^(\+"`

Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: @ ScottC: thank you for your reply! Could you please show me how I would apply this?

Comment: Actually - I think `[\+]` might be the way to go instead of `\+`

Comment: I wonder what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to escape slashes in R strings with an additional slash. A single slash is an escape character. If you need a literal slash you need a double slash in the string

Comment: like this? gsub("\\d+-\d+-\d+\s", "", string, fixed = TRUE)

Comment: Try `sub(" ([[:digit:]-]+)", "", string)`

Comment: Could this code be applied over a column? e.g. file$col = sub(" ([[:digit:]-]+)", "", file$col)?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
library(stringr)

s <- c("a1 123-456-7899 hh", "b 124-123-9999 b3")
result <- str_replace(s, "\\d+[-]\\d+[-]\\d+\\s", "")
print(result)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[1] "a1 hh" "b b3"
```

This will look for :

- `\\d+` : one or more digits, followed by
- `[-]` : a hyphen, followed by
- `\\d+` : one or more digits, followed by
- `[-]` : a hyphen, followed by
- `\\d+` : one or more digits, followed by
- `\\s` : a space

And replace it with `""` - nothing

Comment: I just did ... still not working on my side ... will keep trying to debug! thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Ok - no worries - this may help : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html

Comment: thank you... i wonder why this is not working?