How can I shorten a string to digits and plus signs?
I want to use a string phoneNumber, which is a phone number, to call this number on mobile devices.
How can I shorten the phoneNumber string to just digits and plus signs?
e.g.
phoneNumber = "+49 / 123 - 456.89"
I like to get: "+4912345678"

not exactly, the link features replacing forbidden chars with space, whereas the OP wants to remove the chars completely. @frankmehlhop, does the partial solutions sound as something that you can adjust to your needs?

have you considered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699007

You can use:
var cleanNumber = phoneNumber.Where(c => c == '+' || Char.IsDigit(c));
string result = String.Concat(cleanNumber);

https://dotnetfiddle.net/dybS5e

I would like to use:
string toPhoneNumber(string value) {
    return '+' + string.Concat(value.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)));
}


And what if the number doesn't contain country code? Now you have suddenly added a + in front.

I just answer the question above, my answer doesn't include all cases of the whole universe. @PalleDue
