# Why does numericality validation allow + symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add validation to the mobile number field. I don't want the user to input anything other than integers in this field. So, I used the following:

```
validates :mobile, numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

This works when I enter just the plus sign in the field and an error is promptly displayed. However, if you enter +123 or any other number immediately following the plus sign, the entry is saved without throwing an error. How do I ensure that only whole numbers are accepted?

Answer (score 1):

You validate the field, according [the Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format) as follows:

```
validates :mobile, format: { with: /\A\d+\z/ }
```

**However:** why don't you allow usage `+`, `-`, `(`, `)`, and spaces in a mobile number? If you allow them to match, please refer to the topics: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634139/phone-validation-regex), and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation).