# Codename One Email validation

Tags: codenameone

I have been trying to create a simple Email validation method, that shows the existence of a username@domainname.com, to no success.
I tried this:

```
public boolean validateEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
RE pattern = new RE("^[(a-zA-Z-0-9-\\_\\+\\.)]+@[(a-z-A-z)]+\\.[(a-zA-z)]{2,3}$");
return pattern.match(emailAddress);
}
```

I imported RE from

```
com.codename1.util.regex.RE
```

Each time I test it, I get the Error message:

```
Exception: com.codename1.util.regex.RESyntaxException - Syntax error: Missing operand to closure
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codename One - RegexConstraint to check a valid phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481888/codename-one-regexconstraint-to-check-a-valid-phone-number)

Comment: @Dsenese1 it's no duplicate, both concepts are not same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `RegexConstraint` we use this for email validation:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^`{|}~]|-|_)+@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

I'm pretty awful with regex so I might be completely off... But it seems to me that the `(` and `[` are reversed in your version.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered a very simple way to do this validation. I didn't know it existed:

```
TextArea userName = new TextArea(); 
Validator validator = new Validator();
validator.addConstraint(userName, RegexConstraint.validEmail());
```

If you would like to provide your own Regular expressions for Validation, do the following:

```
RegexConstraint emailConstraint = new RegexConstraint("^[(a-zA-Z-0-9-\\_\\+\\.)]+@[(a-z-A-z)]+\\.[(a-zA-z)]{2,3}$", "Invalid Email Address");
validator.addConstraint(userName, emailConstraint);
```

Then to be sure that the validation is successful, perform the following check :

```
if (!validator.isValid()) {
         ToastBar.showErrorMessage("You have to make all corrections");
       }
```