# jQuery validate phone number

Tags: jquery

I'd like to validate phone number as:
(000) 111-1111
I'm using this snippet, which works fine if the user enters only numbers. but if he started with a brackets, all crashes .. I really would need help ...

```
$("input#phone1,input#phone2").keyup(function() {
        var curchr = this.value.length;
        var curval = $(this).val();
        //var numericReg = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
        var numericReg = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;
        if(!numericReg.test(curval)) {
            $(this).prev('label').append(tag_error + numeric_chars_only + end_tag);
            console.log($(this)+numeric_chars_only);
        }
        if (curchr == 3) {
            $("input#phone1").val("(" + curval + ")" + " ");
        } else if (curchr == 9) {
            $("input#phone1").val(curval + "-");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where are `tag_error`, `numeric_chars_only`, and `end_tag` defined?

Comment: this is only alert fo user ..

Comment: Hiya! hmm I have created this for you - http://jsfiddle.net/5NCQg/18/ Can you show us a demo how do you mean onkeyup validation? :) Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery **OR** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960596/example-of-a-regular-expression-in-jquery-for-phone-numbers might give you better Idea! Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using this:

^(?\d{3})?[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$

It allows 
(555)555-5555,
5555555555,
555 555 5555,
555-555-5555,
(555)-555-5555

ETC.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you need:

```
/^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$/

var x = '(000) 111-1111'.replace(/^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$/, "");
alert(x);​ // alerts empty string. the regular expression worked.
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/V4v96/)

Comment: yes, but if the user starts typing 'brackets' the snippet changes the first char into brcket and then all crashes :S I need to prevent to change the bracket if the user enters

Comment: @AngelM. Can you give an example what do you mean?

Comment: This does not work if there are no brackets or space or dash, I think OP wanted that too :-)

Comment: user start typing in the field: (123 ... end the snippet changes this into ((12) 3 ...

Comment: @altschuler. Then he needs this `/^\(?\d{3}\)? ?\d{3}-?\d{4}$/`

Comment: @AngelM. I don't understand your comments. I give up, I hope someone else will understand better. Good luck!!

Comment: it is the same ... problem is here: if curchr==3, configure the phone number ... but if the curchr[1] == '(' - it should be recognized and not replaced ..