# How to code html table to format telephone numbers?

Tags: html-table, number-formatting, phone-number

How do I code HTML table form to format the phone number field with a dash or space? Example: 000-000-0000
So that user can just enter string of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this library that let's you define the pattern you need and formats it

http://firstopinion.github.io/formatter.js/

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expressions validation. In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960596/example-of-a-regular-expression-in-jquery-for-phone-numbers) you can find regex patterns for different phone patterns.