# C# Regular Expression to validate phone number

Tags: c#, regex

Hi please help  me how to do validations for phone number in c# and the phone numbers must allow only country code followed by mobile Number

Comment: Please add relevant information to your question like what you tried so far with code. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further orientation.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this Post

[regex for phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2842345/764846)

```
/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/
(123) 456 7899
(123).456.7899
(123)-456-7899
123-456-7899
123 456 7899
1234567899
are supported
```