# Regular expression that will match US Phone Numbers?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

So I have to write a regular expression that will match US phone numbers, which can be of the form `x-xxx-xxx-xxxx` or `xxx-xxx-xxxx` or `(xxx)xxx-xxxx` or `xxx-xxxx`. I am not sure if what I have will work though, cause I am unable to test it. Would what I have below work or is there a simpler expression?

```
grep '+?(1[ -])?((\d{3})[ -]|(\d{3}[ -]?)){2}\d{4}'
```

Comment: This might help: [grep with regex for phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2269586/3776858)

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)