# How to grep a telephone number with country code in linux

Tags: linux, grep

How to grep (+(xx)xxx xxx xxx) a type of phone numer like this. I am looking for exacly (+(48)xxx xxx xxx)

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grep with regex for phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269586/grep-with-regex-for-phone-number)

Answer (score 1):

```bash
$ echo '+(48)123 456 768' | grep '+(48)[0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9]'
+(48)123 456 768
```

Comment: Thank your very much, do u know how to grep a EPOCH type of date? @Doj

Comment: @Kvrsa If you have another question - create new one

Comment: @Kvrsa The questions you're asking about are very common. Please use the search box to search for existing questions and answers.